# How to print an object's member in c++ without override operator <<?

Tags: c++, ruby, cout, inspect

I know in ruby language there is a method called  [**object.inspect**](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/inspect)
can print all member's in object without override
toString(Java) <<(in cpp),it's very usefull for debug print.

I want to know How to implment these function in c++ or is there has any library to do this? I'm newer to learn c++, hate to write too much templates for many diffent complex classes!

Thanks for any advise!

Comment: No C++ does not have Reflection. I heard there were plans to add it though.

Comment: @Slava for the last 20 years, I recon

Comment: it seems good news

Comment: You may use debug information but that would be compiler specific and maybe available only in specific cases.

Comment: @SergeyA thanks for your edit